# stub function vs function expression

Tags: javascript, stub

I need to rename a number of javascript functions but for compatibility also need to keep the old name.

I can think of 2 ways:

1. create stub functions
   `function oldFunction(a,b,c) { newFunction(a,b,c) }`
2. or use function expressions
   `var oldFunction = newFunction`

What is the preferred way? Are there any differences concerning performance?

Comment: The assignment seems most performant as it will not go through the call stack, copying the variables. Also, it is the shortest code, you do not need to care about the number of parameters or their name.

Comment: You have to keep in mind the scope of the function using the second method. var oldFunction =..... Will only be available where it is declared. Check This - http://jsfiddle.net/6zLc2obd/

Comment: Also they can't be called before initialization - Note the errors in Console in Developer Tools.  Check This - http://jsfiddle.net/yrwujtdL/

Comment: Thank you for your answers.